# Rubyでサムネイル画像の取得方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Railsを使ってニュースサイトやブログ記事などのフィードを集めるサイトを作っています。そこでURLだけでなく、サムネイル画像も一緒に表示させたいのですが、どのような方法で取得するのがいいのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問の内容が曖昧で、回答する側も質問者さんの状況を勝手に想像しながら回答してしまう状況になっています。なので「このサイトのこのフィードを使って、例えばこの記事のこの画像を表示させたい」「Railsのコードは現在こんなふうになっていて、ここに外部サイトの画像が表示できればベスト」というように、より具体的な情報を追記した方がより確実に期待する回答を得られると思います。

Comment: 今後、質問が曖昧にならないように気をつけたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

もし質問主さんの聞きたいことが、RSSフィードを集めてきてそこから参照できる各ウェブページの中から画像を抽出し、フィードの内容と一緒にサムネイル表示させたい、ということであれば、画像の取り込み方法などはすでに回答された方がおっしゃってるようにpaperclipやその他のgemが使えると思いますが、ページ内のどのコンテンツから画像を取ってくるのか、そのアルゴリズムを決めたいということであれば、タグの構造やmicroformat, wai-aria等の情報を解析して試行錯誤するしかないようにも思います。
もしかしたらその辺をうまく探してくれるツールがあるのかもしれませんが。。。

Answer (score 1):

Rubyの組み込み関数であるsystem を使うのはどうでしょうか
まずURLを文字列処理で取得し,system関数からUnix シェルのwgetを使い画像を取得するというのはどうでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

ウェブサイトのスクリーンショットを、サムネイル画像として保存したいということでしょうか？

ウェブサイトのスクリーンショットを取るためには、Ruby からウェブブラウザを起動して、その表示をキャプチャーする必要があります。WebKit を使う方法など色々ありますが、Selenium を使うサンプルを載せておきます。firefox を事前にインストールしておいてください。

取得したスクリーンショットは、ImageMagick や PaperClip を使えば、サムネイル画像の大きさにリサイズできます。

Gemfileに以下を追加。

```
gem 'headless'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

app/models/capture.rb

```
require 'headless'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class Capture
  def self.run
    Headless.ly do
      driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
      driver.navigate.to 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
      driver.save_screenshot 'screenshot.png'
      driver.quit
    end
  end
end
```

スクリーンショットを取得(Rails.root にscreenshot.png が保存される)

```
pry(main)> Capture.run
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

`paperclip`というgemがおすすめです。
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip